# Cannot connect to rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

Can not connect to internal Rabbit MQ instance. Receive following error:

```
The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Library, code=541, text="Unexpected Exception", classId=0, methodId=0, cause=System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.Frame.ReadFrom(NetworkBinaryReader reader)
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler_0_9.ReadFrame()
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ConnectionBase.MainLoopIteration()
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ConnectionBase.MainLoop()
```

Could it be that my firewall is blocking required port?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. Not sure if would be helpful for someone, but: there was old MassTransit (RabbitMQ client) version, which required to set in URI not just vhost, but also queue address.